# Route/API convention questions

Tags: php, laravel

I have a  web page where I have products and product categories, I have many  pages to show data like  where I show products belonging to a category, I'm scratching my head about how to approach this.

```
//Uses ProductController, shows products
Route::get('/products/category/{id}', 'Web\ProductController@productsCategoryId');

//Uses ProductCategoryController, shows products too
Route::get('/product-category/{id}/products','Web\ProductCategoryController@productCategoriesIdProducts');
```

I have two routes which show the same data, both show products belonging to a category, my heart tells me I should go for the first one in ProductController since I'm ALWAYS showing products, products are the main player per se but I have also seen the second route pattern used, then there's a third option I just thought.

What about forgetting about verbose routes and using query params:

```
/products?category=1
```

Boom, afaik if I do this there would be a single entry point in my controller and from that method depending on the query params I would show different pages, index.blade, show.blade, category.blade.

Using query params make me understand/read the url better imo but I'm worried about having a single method with a bunch of if conditionals is the way to go about this...

I'm open to all kind s of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```html
Route::get('/products/category/{id}?category', 'Web\ProductController@productsCategoryId');
```

```
category=1
```